# Не могу расстянуть div на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу растянуть эту полоску на всю ширину, точнее на 25-150% масштабе в браузере хром все отлично, но 175% и выше - полоса кончается раньше чем контент, вроде как исправляется через `min-width: 1250px` и выше, но мне кажется это неправильно, просто хотел чтобы минимальная ширина была поменьше, да и просто хочется понять почему не растягивается на всю ширину ***пробовал и width:100% и т.д., уже сил нет***

```css
/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Noto Sans, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  min-width: 800px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}

.nav {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #FFD43E;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7a7a7a;
  border-width: 2px 0px;
}

.topinfo {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.topinfo li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="topinfo">
    <li>тут лого</li>
    <li>тут название конторы</li>
    <li>тут краткое инфо</li>
    <li>8 800 555 3535</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="nav">

</div>
<p>Тут будет текст</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так надо ?

```
*{
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

вот это писать не самый лучший вариант так как браузеры уже сделали всё для того что бы отображалось корректно, сбрасывать отступы надо только тем элементам для которых это на самом деле надо

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Noto Sans, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}

.nav {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ffd43e;
  border: 2px solid #7a7a7a;
}

.topinfo {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="topinfo">
    <li>тут лого</li>
    <li>тут название конторы</li>
    <li>тут краткое инфо</li>
    <li>8 800 555 3535</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="nav">

</div>
<p>Тут будет текст</p>
```

Comment: господи спасибо) все работает

Comment: @Evgen161 а отметить решением и пальчик вверх нажать ?

Comment: сорян) я тут еще не разобрался, отметил решение. "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."

Answer (score 0):

вот рабочий css

```
/* CSS Document */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Noto Sans, sans-serif;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

.header {
    height: 100px;
}

.nav {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #FFD43E;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #7a7a7a;
    border-width: 2px 0px;

}

.topinfo {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;

}

.topinfo li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

работает как при увеличении, так и при уменьшении

Comment: ничего не поменялось( проще убрать "display: -webkit-inline-box;" и сделать min-width: 1250px; тогда все отлично на любом масштабе, но это наверно костыль/колхоз

Comment: убирать это "display: -webkit-inline-box;" не нужно, в body убери width: 100%; и при приближении все работает, но при уменьшении начинает все валится, по этому советую обратить внимание на bootstrap там все практически решено

Comment: да я только учусь и лезть еще в бутстрап наверно рано, но это нужно будет  учить конечно 100%, спасибо

Comment: как раз он и рассчитан на простоту, так как там все уже решено, только подставляй значения из учебника, да и все описано все понятно